# WebRtc android sending of message

Tags: android, android-ndk, webrtc

I already have a running webrtc chat from web browser to web browser. Then I found out **AndroidRTC** sample on github [here](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC), it has a module named **webrtc-client**. I am still new to this one.

The module I think is to help do webrtc operations easier like chat and video call. I am not quite sure how to use the module.

Here are my questions:

1. How do you instantiate the WebRtcClient for messaging without video for the moment?
2. Also what are the values for WebRtcClient#sendMessage() method parameters? (like formats).

If you have additional resources for the usage of the library please do also mention them.

Reference
https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

Answer (score 0):

Every peer connection object (org.webrtc.PeerConnection) has its own data channel. So, when you create peer connection, create DataChannel object and pass it to peerConnection object. Also, you need to set observers to that data channel.

**Receiving message**

Observer has interface method

```
 @Override
 public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer) {
     // message received here
 }
```

where you are notified when the message is received. You can then turn the buffer into a string and you can get the message that is sent from, let's say, some web client.

**Sending message**

If you want to send some String to peer connection, convert it to ByteBuffer. Take your data channel object and within send method call:

```
mDataChannel.send(new DataChannel.Buffer(byteBuffer, false));
```

And that's pretty much it.